# exec.Run and argv problem

Tags: go

I want to create an array of exec.Cmd and pipe them together to make an squid authenticator. It works when the commands in *file* have no arguments. With arguments, it only reads **EOF**. I've checked the argv array and its content is ok.

The relevant portion of the code is:

```
func initCmd(file *os.File) []* exec.Cmd {
    var cmd     [MAX_PROC]* exec.Cmd;
    var e       os.Error

    // Initialize the commands in the config file
    environ := os.Environ();
    var i int
    for i=0; i < MAX_PROC; i++ {
        line := getLine(file)
        if line == "" { break }
        parts := strings.Fields(line)
        cmd[i], e = exec.Run(parts[0], parts[1:], environ, 
                             exec.Pipe, exec.Pipe, exec.Pipe)
        exitOnError(&e)
    }
    return cmd[0:i]
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

**PS:** If it helps, the complete program source is at [github](http://github.com/jdinuncio/cascadeauth/blob/master/cascadeauth.go).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The args need to include arg0 also. Try exec.Run(parts[0], parts)

I opened an issue about how this is confusing, but they claim it's working as intended:
http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=428

Comment: Now that's ugly API design. With keyword arguments they could have aped the way nicer subprocess: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Comment: It's ugly because they more or less copied the behavior of the standard C library functionality, which is also why they claim it's working as intended. In fact, they're probably just calling one of the many variants of the C function "exec" under the hood.